# AFNetworking an empty array as a parameter

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I'm trying to pass an empty array as a parameter.

```
[self POST:@"offers.json" parameters:@{ @"offer": @{ @"key": [NSArray new] } } success:success failure:failure];
```

But AFNetworking cuts that parameter and didn't sent it.

Any help?

Comment: How do you know that the parameter is really omitted? Would it be possible to give us an idea of the actual request (via accessing `currentRequest` of the data task - or any other means)?

Comment: Which serialiser are you using?

Comment: @Alladinian I can assure that the whole parameter is really omitted if it gets the empty array :-) I'm struggling with it too. Have you solved it?

Comment: @SashaKid hey man! I probably didn't solve it and moved to Alamofire :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand, it's common issue and not AFNetworking bug, this line of code helped me
`sessionManager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];`
https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/1722

Comment: Nice! Maybe it will save some time for someone else.